# Is it bad design to return API response formatted with markdown?

Tags: angularjs, grails, markdown

I'm building an SPA, using Grails on the server and Angular on the client.

As a simple example, let's say that there's a registration form which gets validated sever-side before sending the error messages back to the user. Currently I'm using the i18n support built in to Grails by adding new message codes to *messages.properties* like this:

`user.phone.error=[{2}] is not a valid phone number`

I want to style my message for the user, so I am replacing the brackets with `<strong/>` using the following helper function:

```
utils.formatMessage = function(message, args) {
    return message.replace(/\[{(\d+)\}\]/g, function(_, idx) {
      var msg += '<strong>';
      msg += args[idx];
      msg += '</strong>';
      return msg;
    });
  };
```

This works well enough, but what if I want to wrap certain text with `<strong/>` and another portion with `<em/>`?

I **could** add another notation to my *messages.properties* like `[[{0}]]`, but it does not seem to be a good longterm solution...

What if instead, I leveraged Markdown to wrap my API responses:
(`**{2}** is not a valid phone number`) and then used a client-side library like [Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) or the [Angular Markdown Directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive) (which uses Showdown) to parse the response?

On the one hand it seems obvious to decouple the API response from the presentation layer, but on the other hand, I don't think that Markdown is going anywhere soon and is incredibly simple as evidenced by this *StackOverflow* post.

Naturally I would limit the usage to Emphasis (`<em/>` and `<strong/>`), leaving all other formatting (Headers, Links, Lists, etc..) at the discretion of the client.

Am I setting myself up for a slippery slope?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is best idea. Javascript is basically JSON so, when you return JSON from your API you can easily parse it on client. And also you can connect other clients in other languages pretty easy. Sure you can do it with Markdown too but it isn't best solution for api responds if you need to work with this api in javascript. JSON is widely used for api responds and I can only recommend it to you.

Comment: to be honest I don't understand your response at all. javascript *is not json* and markdown is nothing but text mixed with a bit of html. There is no parsing involved within the ajax transfer and if it was sent by itself it is no different than sending any other html

Comment: @tomas @charlietfl To clarify, I am still wrapping the entire response in JSON `{"status":"error","message":"Please verify your inputs.","errors":[{"message":"**{0}** is not a valid phone number","args":["5555555"]}]}`

Comment: I didnt understand it. You are using json and for formatting you send markdown representation of message. I think that this is fine. I thought that you would like to create whole api and send only markdown text responses.

Answer (score 0):

My attitude is if the browser renders it and it's safe and secure...why not!

Markdown is simply text anyway with a little mix of html. I can't see any downsides to doing this

You might consider sending it in a json wrapper and then you can include other properties along with the markdown source